# ActionBarSherlock and some kind of overriding setTitle method

Tags: android, android-layout, actionbarsherlock

I'm using ActionBarSherlock and a lot of fragments in my application use setTitle method, for example:

```java
getActivity().setTitle(articleName);
```

But I am using custom styling for ActionBar and when changing title I want to change it on my TextView.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@color/grey"
            android:id="@+id/bar_title"
            style="@style/Text.Medium">
    </TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Is it possible to, maybe, override setTitle and add my own code to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Since the [`setTitle`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setTitle%28int%29) method is not final you can override it within your `Activity` and then use it from within your `Fragment`.